# Duplicate Form on click using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

```
  addDetails() {
     const divCreate = document.createElement('div');
     divCreate.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some text'));
     divCreate.setAttribute('class', 'bg-secondary');
     document.getElementById('mainForm').appendChild(divCreate);
  }
```

The image attached is my form, and onclick I want to add similar form, and once done will submit all values to db.

Comment: please post the code that you have tried

Comment: addDetails() {
     const divCreate = document.createElement('div');
      divCreate.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some text'));
      divCreate.setAttribute('class', 'bg-secondary');
       document.getElementById('mainForm').appendChild(divCreate);
  }
This is what I tried of creating using multiple attribute, but was not helpful

Comment: please add code to the question body

Comment: Okay done with changes

Comment: So what is your question? That function not doing what you want? (Don’t see even an attempt to create actual form elements in there.) _“onclick I want to add similar form, and once done will submit all values to db”_ - then you don’t want to add an actual extra _form_ (those submit individually only), but another set of form elements to the same, already existing form.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the following way (you will need to add validation too but here is a plain working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3cztw):

**Html code**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of formDataList;let i = index;">
<form  >
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.detail" name="detail" />
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.amount" name="amount" />
  <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="item.date" name="date" />
  <button (click)="removeItem(item)"> remove </button>
</form>
</div>

<form #addForm="ngForm" >
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.detail" name="detail" />
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.amount" name="amount" />
  <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="data.date" name="date" />
  <br/>
  <button (click)="addItem(data)"> add  </button>
</form>
```

**Ts code :**

```
   public data = { };
   public formDataList = [];

   addItem($item){
       this.formDataList.push($item)
       this.data = {};
    }

   removeItem($item){
       this.formDataList.splice( this.formDataList.indexOf($item),1)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy...that was what I was looking for..I tried with one form actually...