# Fill Edit form Checkboxes with data from API - Angular

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, api, checkbox

I cant seem to find a proper example of how to fill a checkbox with values from an API when a form is in edit mode.

I have a service that fetches roles data from an API. Each role can have multiple permissions like edit-user, create-user, create-product, edit-product, etc. I want a form where a user can edit these role permissions using checkboxes. I have tried using patchValue as shown below but it doesnt respond to anything so far.

```
  rolePermissionList = [];
  permissionList = [];

  setupForm() {

    this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
      role_name: ["", Validators.required],
      description: [""],
      status: [""],
      permissions: this.fb.array([]),
    }, {updateOn: 'change'});

  }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.setupForm();

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {

      this.id = parseInt(params.get("id"));

      // fetch single role record
      this.getPageData(this.id);

    })

  }

  // get page data
  async getPageData(role_id) {

    this.spinner.show();

    // get role
    await this.getRole(role_id);

    // get all permissions
    await this.getPermissions();

    // get role permissions
    await this.getRolePermissions(role_id);

    this.spinner.hide();

  }
```

I have two services: one that returns the entire permissions list, and the other that returns permissions assigned to the current role. I want a way to check only permissions assigned to the current role being edited. These are the functions that fetch all permissions and rolepermissions:

```
// get permissions list

getPermissions() {

    this.permissionService.getPermissionsList()

      .subscribe(

        data => {

          console.log("permissions === ", data);

          this.permissionList = data;

        },

        error => console.log(error));

  }



  // get role permissions
  getRolePermissions(role_id?:any) {

    // if role_id is supplied
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (role_id) {
      params=params.set('role_id', role_id.toString());
    }

    this.rolePermissionService.getRolePermissionsList(params)
      .subscribe(
        data => {

          // store fetched data
          this.rolePermissionList = data;

          // extract permission name from returned array
          var arrayOfPerms = data.map(function(obj) {
            return obj.name;
          });

          // patch data
          this.roleForm.pastchValue('permissions', arrayOfPerms);

        },
        error => {

          console.log(error);

        });

  }
```

The front end:

```
...

<div class="row" *ngIf="permissionList; else loading">

   <div *ngFor="let permission of permissionList; let i=index" class="col-md-6">

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2 m-b-15">
         <input type="checkbox"
          [value]="permission.id"
          (change)="onCheckChange($event)"
          class="custom-control-input"
          id="checkbox-{{ i }}">

       <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-{{ i }}">{{  permission.display_name }}</label>
      </div>

   </div>

</div>

...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Do you mind creating a Sample StackBlitz to work with? You can get the data from a `json`  file in the `assets` folder via `HttpClient`. Just supply the url of `/assets/data.json` in the call to `HttpClient`'s `get` method. Please share the link to the sample stackblitz. Or you could fork this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-table-for-student-data-in-angular?file=src/app/app.component.html) that I just created for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656214/2622292)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the setup a bit, and iterate a formarray in the template instead of `permissionList`. Also I would return the id:

```ts
var arrayOfPerms = data.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
```

Since your `permissionList` is using the `id` as value.

So this is how the form would look before edit. Here I have omitted the http-request and hard coded the values:

```ts
permissionList = [
  { id: 1, displayName: 'Admin' },
  { id: 2, displayName: 'User' },
  { id: 3, displayName: 'SuperUser' }
];

rolePermissionList = [1, 3];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  // set all checkboxes as false initially
  const ctrls = this.permissionList.map(control => this.fb.control(false));

  this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
    permissions: this.fb.array(ctrls),
  });
}

// for being able to shorten
get permissionsArr() {
  return this.roleForm.get('permissions') as FormArray;
}

submit() {
  // filter the checked and store in array
  const selectedRoles= this.roleForm.value.permissions
    .map((checked, i) => checked ? this.permissionList[i].id : null)
    .filter(value => value !== null);
  // here is an array of ids, e.g [1, 3]
  console.log(selectedRoles)
}
```

and the relevant template part:

```html
<label formArrayName="permissions" *ngFor="let perm of permissionsArr.controls; index as i">
  <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
  {{permissionList[i].displayName}}
</label>
```

So when that is done, and you want to patch values, just call a function that checks which id's that match in `permissionList`, and use `patchValue()` on the form control:

```ts
patchValue() {
  this.permissionList.map((perm, i) => {
    if (this.rolePermissionList.indexOf(perm.id) !== -1) {
      this.permissionsArr.at(i).patchValue(true)
    }
  })
}
```

**Here is a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bni7nr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) demo.**

Comment: Thanks this worked for me with some minor changes. Cheers.

Comment: Great, awesome, glad I could help you on the way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Patching or reseting form array is pretty annoying, you can check this [article](https://dev.to/crazedvic/using-patchvalue-on-formarrays-in-angular-7-2c8c).

You need to update your array with the necessary length.

- you can add or remove formControl in your array depending if you have more or less item when you want to patch the vaue.

Comment: Is it possible to patch an array of checkboxes in angular? I know this question must be having a simple answer, I just cant figure it out...

Comment: Yes you can. But your array need to have the correct length.