# Patch value on form array not setting value on material multiple select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to patch value an array of ids from Firestore into a mat-select with multiple options. I am looping through the array and creating a new form control for each id and then using the reactive form push method to add to the formArray. Like so:

```
patchValueForm(portfolio: any) {
 this.formGroup.patchValue(portfolio);

 for (const id of portfolio.property_ids) {
   const control = new FormControl(id);
   if (!this.property_ids.getRawValue().includes(id)) {
     this.property_ids.push(control);
   }
}
console.log(this.formGroup.getRawValue()); }
```

This does seem to patch the value into the form as shown from the console log:

[image]

The problem that I am having is that its then not pre populating the material select shown here:

[image]

The HTML that I am using for this part is:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-select [formArrayName]="'property_ids'" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let property of properties; let i = index" 
                        (onSelectionChange)="updatePropertyIdArray(property.property_id)" >
              {{property?.address?.first_line_address}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error>Please select at least one property</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

I have searched everywhere online and tried multiple different methods, but still ca not seem to populate the select. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: It can be similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656063/fill-edit-form-checkboxes-with-data-from-api-angular/58656324?noredirect=1#comment103620464_58656324)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a simple formControl instead of the formArray in the mat select. The formControl holds the selection array and u can use formControlName.

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-select [formControlName]="'property_ids'" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let property of properties; let i = index" [value]="property.property_id" 
                    (onSelectionChange)="updatePropertyIdArray(property.property_id)" >
          {{property?.address?.first_line_address}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error>Please select at least one property</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

You also need the value binding in the mat option to make the select work properly.

Comment: Sorry I think im missing something, could you show how to have a formControl with an array value please?

Comment: @Jm3s The formControl can hold any value like objects and arrays. You can create such a formControl like `new FormControl([])` or   `new FormGroup({properties: []})`